# Why can't I access protected java method even thought I've extended the class?

Tags: java, inheritance, protected

Here's the documentation for the protected method:

```
/** Converts jmusic score data into a MIDI Sequence */
protected  javax.sound.midi.Sequence scoreToSeq(Score score)
```

And I made this little class to extend the class that scoreToSeq method comes from:

```
public class MidiSequence extends MidiSynth{

    public Sequence getSequence(Score score){
        MidiSynth synth = new MidiSynth();
        Sequence sequence = null;
        try
        {
                    // Here I get the error saying that the method has
                    // protected access in MidiSynth
            sequence = synth.scoreToSeq(score);

        }
        catch (InvalidMidiDataException e)
        {
            /*
             *  In case of an exception, we dump the exception
             *  including the stack trace to the console.
             *  Then, we exit the program.
             */
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }

        return sequence;

    }
}
```

Comment: From Najib Tounsi (not enough rep to comment) : Even though, `synth.scoreToSeq(score);` should be legal.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

(EDIT: [theycallmemorty's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622219/why-cant-i-access-protected-java-method-even-thought-ive-extended-the-class/1622235#1622235) gives the practical advice to avoiding this problem in your case. This answer gives the reasons for why you have to follow that advice, i.e. why the language has been designed that way.)

You can only access a protected member of another object which is of the same type as the accessing code (or a subclass) - even though the member is *declared* in a supertype.

From the [Java Language Specification, section 6.6.2](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/names.html#6.6.2):

> Let C be the class in which a
>   protected member m is declared. Access
>   is permitted only within the body of a
>   subclass S of C. In addition, if Id
>   denotes an instance field or instance
>   method, then:
>
> - If the access is by a qualified name Q.Id, where Q is an ExpressionName,
>     then the access is permitted if and
>     only if the type of the expression Q
>     is S or a subclass of S.
> - If the access is by a field access expression E.Id, where E is a Primary
>     expression, or by a method invocation
>     expression E.Id(. . .), where E is a
>     Primary expression, then the access is
>     permitted if and only if the type of E
>     is S or a subclass of S.

This is to allow a type to access members relevant to its own inheritance tree, without defeating encapsulation of other classes. For example, suppose we have:

```
     A
    / \
   B   Other
  /
 C
```

and A declared a protected member `x`. Without the rule working the way it does, you could get round encapsulation by putting a member in `Other`:

```
public int getX(A a)
{
    return a.x;
}
```

and just calling that passing in an instance of `B` or `C` - the member would effectively become public, because you could always work around it by introducing another class... not a good idea. With the current rule, you'd have to subclass `B` or `C` - which you may not be able to in the first place.

Comment: I think I (mostly) understand the JLS excerpt :-), but the counterexample doesn't seem convincing. The protected field x is on A not on B or C so it should be ok for Other to see it. It doesn't expose other fields from either B or C.

Of course this is mostly hairsplitting since the answer is "the spec says so" and it is rather improbable for us to change the spec :-)

Comment: @Jon What do you mean by "because you could always work around it by introducing another class" in your second last line?

Comment: @Geek: Anyone could just create another class which extends `A` and provides access for an instance of *any other* subclass of `A`.

Comment: @JonSkeet I have asked a [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15354816/what-is-the-difference-between-qualified-name-and-a-field-access-expression) here. Can you please provide an answer?

Comment: I think the last example should be:
`public static void getX(A a) {return a.x;}`

Comment: @DavidAlves: More than that - it needs a return type too :) Fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 15):

By doing this:

```
MidiSynth synth = new MidiSynth();
sequence = synth.scoreToSeq(score);
```

You are not actually taking advantage of the fact that you've extended the MidiSynth class.

If you were to try

```
this.scoreToSec(score);
```

Then you'll find you have access to the protected function.

Comment: Or by creating a new MidiSequence instead of a MidiSynth (and changing the type of the synth variable too).